# npm publish node.js module and yet can not find module after npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

thanks your time advance.

first, I publish npm package success.(verified that already in the npmjs.com profile, the package name I can call 'firstnpmpublish'(uniqueness))

second, write require('firstnpmpublish') in my test.js file and type npm install firstnpmpublish

third , type node test.js in the terminal on my mac.
but it print:

```
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'firstnpmpublish'
```

I have tried 'npm install firstnpmpublish' and 'npm install firstnpmpublish -g' and also 'npm install' as I create package.json which dependencise include firstnpmpublish. but it still doesn't work.

however, instead of require('firstnpmpublish') and using require('express'),it work smoothly.

where i was wrong? thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure the package was published successfully? https://www.npmjs.com/package/firstnpmpublish doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: of course, the firstnpmpublish just fake name. you can search intaprint that my package.

Comment: install using this npm install firstnpmpublish --save and then check in package.json is it installed successfully or not

Comment: @ShekharTyagi it can not work as well.

Comment: is it save in ur package.json

Comment: @ShekharTyagi yes it saved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [package.json](https://unpkg.com/intaprint@1.0.0/package.json) file doesn't specify the path to your main file, so the `require` can't be resolved. Add the following to your package.json and then republish:

```
"main": "Print.js"
```

I'd recommend renaming that file to `index.js` though, to better fit with the Node conventions.

Comment: I add the "main":"Print.js" but it doesn't work. and yet I check expressjs package, there is no "main":"index.js" in the package.json

Comment: Yes, you are right, I change the Print.js to index.js. it works. thanks~

Comment: @suoyong: Glad I could help :) If I recall correctly, `index.js` is what it looks for by default if the main file isn't specified. That's why Express doesn't have that entry in its `package.json` - [they follow the naming convention](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/index.js).

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue. Removing the entire node_modules folder and re-installing worked for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: first of all, it does not create node_modules when using npm install package name.  only using package.json will creat node_modules.

Comment: those modules save in package.json , command npm install will install all the modules that is saved in package.json.

Comment: I was getting the OP's error (on the `seedrandom`, `three` and `tippy.js` packages only) and nuking `node_modules` and reinstalling resolved the problem.  Gremlins.